# How to make git ignore files created by the building process in a new directory?

Tags: git

I am in git repository and created a new directory with some subdirs and files. after building was created some files (e.g. `module.ssysn` ). After building git ask me to track those files even though in other directories in the same git repository it doesn't ask me to track them. I tried the following:

I used `git rm --cached module.ssysn` and `git update-index --assume-unchanged module.ssysn` but both fails with:

```
fatal: pathspec module.ssysn didn't match any files
```

or

```
fatal: unable to mark file module.ssysn
```

Comment: you need to describe your problem in more detail, maybe a step a step command history, to get a satisfied answer to solve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the message unclearly states, your git repository doesn't have any tracked file with that name.

You only need those commands if you want to repository to stop tracking files that are already added.

Comment: How can I make git to ignore them?

Comment: Just add them to `.gitignore`.

Comment: Then what problem are you seeing?